# pyautogui - pass parameters to hotkey?

Tags: python, pyautogui

The keys I want **pyautogui** to press **come from a string**, that is parsed to an array

so instead of doing this:

```
pyautogui.hotkey('alt','f')
```

I tried this:

```
keys = "alt+f" # comes from config file
sub_keys = keys.split("+")
pyautogui.hotkey(sub_keys)
```

tried this too: pyautogui.hotkey(*sub_keys)

tried a tuple:

```
_sub_keys = tuple(sub_keys)
pyautogui.hotkey(*_sub_keys)
```

tried passing the array directly to hotkey()

```
pyautogui.hotkey(keys)
```

I also tried this:

```
for key in sub_keys:
   pyautogui.keyDown(key)
   time.sleep(0.2)
for key in sub_keys[::-1]:
   pyautogui.keyUp(key)
   time.sleep(0.2)
```

nothing works, **it is like the 'alt' key is pressed, but not the 'f' key**

what am I missing ?

[image]

Comment: Since you're reading from a config file, you might want to do a `.strip()` on `keys` before `.split("+")`. I wonder if a newline character is preventing the `f` from registering. So `sub_keys = keys.strip().split("+")`. Then do the argument unpacking version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed, looking at my logs, there were extra characters that needed to be stripped

```
sub_keys = keys.strip().split("+")
```